# If 20 items have 95% chance for X, can X be expected to happen for 19?

Tags: probability, statistics

When conducting a survey, confidence level of 95% means (I know it is not exact interpretation) that I can be that much sure about the interval covering the correct value/mean.

Therefore I have 20 questions, each with 95% probability of including the correct value within the margin of error and also 5% probability of being out of margin of error. 
Can I then say that 1 (5% of 20) can be expected as out of margin of error?

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/882/).

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, you say that 1 can be expected as out of margin of error. But be careful, it is **expected**, or it won't always happen.